# Does a route need to be in the RIB in order to be redistributed?

Tags: routing, bgp, ospf, eigrp, rip

Please can anyone help me confirming something : Is every protocol (OSPF, RIP, EIGRP,BGP) needs to have the route in the RIB in order to be able to REDISTRIBUTE it into another protocol ? Is there any exception ?

Comment: A routing protocol needs to have a route to a network in order to be able to redistribute it to another routing protocol. For example, if OSPF doesn't know about `10.11.12.0/24` it can't tell BGP about that route. A routing protocol can't tell what it doesn't know.

Comment: Sometimes the route is known (ie in the DB) but not in the RIB

Comment: Then you can redistribute it. That doesn't mean that the routing protocol receiving it will use it. Routes which are not actually used are propagated by routing protocols all the time.

Comment: Sure, it's propagated, but redistributed in another protocol is another story ...

Comment: Not really. Redistribution is just a form of propagation.

Comment: Sorry, but this is false, BGP can have a route  in it's DB topology, yet it can have a RIB failure. Since will not be installed in the RIB, it can't be redistributed in another protocol

Comment: I know that if you have the same route from both EIGRP and OSPF, by default, the EIGRP route is in the RIB (`show ip route` shows the RIB), but not the OSPF route, which is in the OSPF database. You can redistribute the OSPF route into BGP.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/8606-redist.html

Note: The mechanics of route redistribution is proprietary on Cisco routers. The rules for redistribution on a Cisco router dictate that the redistributed route be present in the routing table. It is not sufficient that the route be present in the routing topology or database.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the IOS version, and, since it is proprietary, it can be changed at any time. I'm just telling you what I observed once: the  EIGRP route was in the routing table, but the OSPF route was redistributed into BGP. The OSPF route wasn't used once the traffic got to the router. The engineer assumed it would be, but the traffic went via the interface EIGRP dictated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/8606-redist.html

> Note: The mechanics of route redistribution is proprietary on Cisco
>   routers. The rules for redistribution on a Cisco router dictate that
>   the redistributed route be present in the routing table. It is not
>   sufficient that the route be present in the routing topology or
>   database.